# Why can I retrieve the value from a HashMap with a different object?

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote an `Employee` class with `eid` and `ename` with setters and getters and I override `equals()` and `hashcode()`.

Now I wrote another class `HashMapTest` in which I created three `Employee` objects. I added two of them to the `HashMap` and the third one is same as the first employee object.

My HashMapTest class is below:

```
public class HashMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setEid(1);
        e1.setEname("Ganesh");

        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        e2.setEid(1);
        e2.setEname("Mahesh");

        Map<Employee, String> map = new HashMap<Employee, String>();
        map.put(e1, "Software Developer");
        map.put(e2, "Software Test Engineer");

        Employee e3 = new Employee();
        e3.setEid(1);
        e3.setEname("Ganesh");

        System.out.println("Getting employee e3 details " + map.get(e3));
    }
}
```

I am not adding `e3` to the `HashMap`, but I'm still getting it from the `HashMap`.

Please explain the logic behind this.

Comment: your equals and hashcode method have problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is that a `Map` gives you out the same value for the same key. Your `e3` is exactly the same as `e1` (from the map's persepective, since you've overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()`), and you did add a `String` with `e1` as the key into the map.

Comment: But I didnt add the e3 to the Map.Then how it will come from the map.

Comment: You add a String to the map with e1 as the key. Now any object that is equal to e1 (like e3) will retrieve the String, that's how Maps work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how equals and hashcode method has been implemented in your Employee class.If it has been so implemented to consider objects having same values as equal objects,of course it would fetch

Answer (score 0):

e3 has the same field values as e1.  Thus, as far as the map is concerned, it's equivalent to e1.  You're looking it up by the same key and are therefore returning the value you added for e1, "Software Developer."

Answer (score 0):

`map.get(Object)` will look for an object in the `HashMap` that exists in there based on the rules defined in `.equals()` and `hashCode()`. Therefore it will return the object that is identical to the searched one (the first object in your case).

Answer (score 0):

That basically depends on the implementation of the `Employee` class methods `equals` and `hashCode`.

Your implementation certainly does return the same value for `e3` than from either `e1` and `e2`.

The Map stores `Employee`s and maps them to `String`. If you ask for `e3` the map will look, if it already contains `e3` and does this according to the rules you've implemented with `equals` and `hashmap`. If it finds an entry, which has the same value there, it will return it - thus I suspect that either `e1` or `e2` have the same values as `e3` there.

If the implementation is based on 'eid' and 'ename' than `e1.equals(e3)` and `e1.hashCode() == e3.hashCode()` and thus they are interchangeable.

A *word of warning*: Using mutable classes as keys in maps can lead to problems if you mutate (change) the values afterwards. To try this out, just do the following:

```
 map.put(e1);
 e1.setEid(3);
 e1.setEname("foo");
 System.out.println(map.contains(e1));   // Will print 'false'
```

I would either recommend not to do this, make the class immutable (that is, make the fields `final`) or be absolutely sure that no one is gonna change them (which will happen sooner or later anyway...)